# Маленькая пауза или задержка функции

Tags: android

Создаю простой quiz app с 4 вариантами. Приложение работает таким образом: Пользователь отвечает на вопрос (нажимает один из четырех кнопок(вариантов)), появляется следующий вопрос и т.д. Так получилось, что придется обойтись без обработчика нажатия, для показа следующего вопроса. Хотелось бы сделать маленькую паузу длиной 1-2 секунды перед показом следующего вопроса, то есть после ответа пользователя, чтобы он увидел и запомнил правильный ответ. Как можно сделать такую паузу(задержку)? Можно ли задавать временное ограничение?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать хэндлер, внутрь поместить вызов вашего метода и запустить хэндлер с задержкой, указанной в миллисекундах.

примерно так:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //тут вызов вашего метода
            doSomething();
        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500); //в данном случае, стоит 1.5 секунды
```